# Inline form using html/css

Tags: html, css, forms

I am still learning WordPress and HTML/css. I am working on embedding an email signup form on my website using Klaviyo. I was given the basic code from their form creator that would have everything in one line (most of the code below is original, added the Zip Code form.)

```
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .klaviyo_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG,
        .klaviyo_condensed_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG {
          font-family: Arial;
        }
        .klaviyo_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG label,
        .klaviyo_condensed_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG label {
          color:#222;
        }
        .klaviyo_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG input[type=text],
        .klaviyo_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG input[type=email],
        .klaviyo_condensed_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG input[type=text],
        .klaviyo_condensed_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG input[type=email] {
          border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .klaviyo_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG .klaviyo_submit_button,
        .klaviyo_condensed_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG .klaviyo_submit_button {
          background-color:#F10382;
          border-radius: 3px;
        }
        .klaviyo_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG .klaviyo_submit_button:hover,
        .klaviyo_condensed_styling.klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG .klaviyo_submit_button:hover {
          background-color:#222222;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="email_signup" class="klaviyo_condensed_styling klaviyo_condensed_float klaviyo_condensed_embed_MMaJiG" action="//manage.kmail-lists.com/subscriptions/subscribe" data-ajax-submit="//manage.kmail-lists.com/ajax/subscriptions/subscribe" method="GET" target="_blank" novalidate="novalidate" style="margin-left: 50%">
        <input type="hidden" name="g" value="MMaJiG">
        <div class="klaviyo_field_group">
            <label for="k_id_email">Newsletter Sign Up</label>
            <input type="email" value="" name="email" id="k_id_email" placeholder="Your Email"/>
            <input type="number" value="" name="zip" id="k_id_zip_code" placeholder="Your Zip Code"/>
        </div>
        <div class="klaviyo_messages">
            <div class="success_message" style="display:none;"></div>
            <div class="error_message" style="display:none;"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="klaviyo_form_actions">
            <button type="submit" class="klaviyo_submit_button">Subscribe</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//www.klaviyo.com/media/js/public/klaviyo_subscribe.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        KlaviyoSubscribe.attachToForms('#email_signup', {
        hide_form_on_success: true
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

I want all form fields (email and zip code) and the submit button all in one line.

The current issue I'm facing is I am seeing 3 different views, on the Klaviyo site it looks like this(its grayed out but you can see it):

[image: Klaviyo View]
When loading the raw HTML it looks like this:

[image: raw html]

On my website:

[image: Website]

Comment: First things first. Your doctype is incorrect and you are in "quirks mode". It should be `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Fix that and let us know where you stand.

Comment: Thanks, had no idea about that, didn't change anything though.

Comment: The fact that you have three different views on three different situations is disturbing and I don't know how we can replicate that to help you.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is most likely that the `div` elements inside the `form` are block elements, which by default are 100% wide and therefore stack below each other.

Try adding this rule to define all these divs as inline-blocks (which can be aligned in one line if the available space allows it):

```
form#email_signup > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: it works with the raw html but on my site it doesn't. I'm using wordpress for my site, could that be the culprit?

Comment: depends... A reason could be other CSS rules which overrule this one due to specifity. You should check with the browser tools which rules apply to those DIVs and what selectors they have. Then use these selectors in your own stylesheet to apply `display: inline-block` to these elements.